# How to access quests that are required for certain building?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

When looking at potential buildings I can make, some of them say they require level x and completing some [quest](http://simpsonswiki.net/wiki/The_Simpsons:_Tapped_Out_quests).  Unfortunately, I've surpassed some of the levels required for these buildings but I can not seem to get the quest to be offered by any of the resident of my town. Is there any way I can trigger certain residents to offer me new quests?

Comment: Playing the game and completing the quests you currently have should eventually unlock the quests you need for buildings IIRC

Comment: I have all my current quests complete.. Everyone is just going about their normal tasks now making expz & money

Comment: Did you build all the buildings to get all the characters then? If you did then I don't know what it is.

Comment: Maybe I'm just impatient, so as to not answer my own question, wanna combine your comments and add the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing the game and completing the quests you currently have will eventually unlock new buildings. Once you do have those buildings build them to unlock new characters, each having their own new quests to complete.